# Riemann tensor in linearized gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

Assuming that $g_{\mu \nu}(x) = η_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}(x)$, determine the first-order form of $R_{\lambda \mu \nu}^{\rho}$ in $h_{\mu \nu}$. The resulting theory is known as linearized gravity.

From the definition of the Riemann tensor and the connection coefficients in terms of the metric tensor, I have that the Riemann tensor in terms of the metric tensor is:

\begin{gather*}
     R_{\sigma \mu \nu}^{\rho}= \frac{1}{2}[\partial_{\mu}g^{\rho \alpha}(\partial_{\nu}g_{\sigma \alpha}+\partial_{\sigma}g_{\nu \alpha}-\partial_{\alpha}g_{\nu \sigma})+ g^{\rho \alpha}(\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}g_{\sigma \alpha}+\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\sigma}g_{\nu \alpha}-\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\alpha}g_{\nu \sigma})\\ - ( \partial_{\nu}g^{\rho \beta}(\partial_{\mu}g_{\sigma \beta}+\partial_{\sigma}g_{\mu \beta}-\partial_{\beta}g_{\mu \sigma}) + g^{\rho \beta}(\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}g_{\sigma \beta}+\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\sigma}g_{\mu \beta}-\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\beta}g_{\mu \sigma}))] \\
    + \frac{1}{4}[(g^{\rho \gamma}(\partial_{\mu}g_{\lambda \gamma}+\partial_{\lambda}g_{\mu \gamma}-\partial_{\gamma}g_{\mu \lambda}))(g^{\lambda \eta}(\partial_{\nu}g_{\sigma \eta}+\partial_{\sigma}g_{\nu \eta}-\partial_{\eta}g_{\nu \sigma})) \\
   - (g^{\rho \theta}(\partial_{\nu}g_{\lambda \theta}+\partial_{\lambda}g_{\nu \theta}-\partial_{\theta}g_{\nu \lambda}))(g^{\lambda \omega}(\partial_{\mu}g_{\sigma \omega}+\partial_{\sigma}g_{\mu \omega}-\partial_{\omega}g_{\mu \sigma}))] 
\end{gather*}

From here I plan to substitute $g$, is that correct or is there another simpler method?

Comment: What is „first order” and how are these two words going to help you?

Comment: I suggest linearizing the inverse metric and the Christoffel symbols first.

Comment: This sounds like homework.  It may be advanced homework, but doesn't the homework rule apply here ?

Comment: See Carroll ch. 7 - he outlines the steps and @G.Smith is right, linearizing the Christoffels is where you should start